# Connecting a branch with Heroku Pipeline

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, codeship

My app is being hosted on Heroku. It's connected to Master branch on Bitbucket. The flow I follow for pushing the app to heroku is:

```
localCode -> Bitbuket Master -> CodeShip -> Heroku
```

I want to push newest changes to a Dev Pipeline on heroku and later on promote it to production pipeline.

I have a DEV branch on Bitbucket which contains the untested latest code.

The problem is, I can't connect the DEV branch on bitbucket to Heroku. I am not sure what can be the cause for it?

I am not using HEROKU cli for managing my apps since I am pushing the code to git and rest gets taken care of automatically - at least in the case of Master Branch.
Excuse my illiteracy in this area. Still learning.

Comment: Are you using https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration for automatic deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure more than one deployment pipeline on Codeship. For each of those pipelines you can configure where and how to deploy the application.

It seems you already have a deployment pipeline with a Heroku deployment configured for the `master` branch.

You can configure a similar deployment pipeline for the `dev` branch, and deploy to a different Heroku application. Please see https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/deployment-pipelines/ for more information on this.

This would not make use of Heroku pipelines though (not sure if this is a requirement though).

Comment: also: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines